# Writing to file whenever signal turns to 1

Tags: file, verilog

I am implementing hardware in Verilog and I want to dump certain signal values to output file whenever one signal turns 1. I have used $fmonitor but problem is it dumps the result whenever there is change in signal. I want to dump certain values say the state of state machine whenever signal value turn 1.

Comment: I think there is an easy solution, to use `$monitor` and then use `grep` command  for your output.

Answer (score 1):

```
always @ (posedge [your signal])
begin

   $fwrite([file], [format], [value]); // or $monitor in your case

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1)
begin
    if(signal == 1)
        $fwrite(file, format, value);
end
```

Another solution is to use $monitor, as suggested earlier.